# model with CrossEntropyLoss criterion doesnt apply softmax pytorch

Tags: pytorch, torch, torchvision

I am using `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` in as my criterion in a model that I am developing. The problem that I am having is that the model outputs a vector of size `(batchsize, #classes)` when it is supposed to output a `(batchsize)` vector.

Isn't `CrossEntropyLoss` supposed to apply `LogSoftmax`?

Here's my Dataset:

```
class DatasetPlus(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, root_img, root_data, width, hight, transform=None):
        self.root_img = root_img
        self.root_data = root_data
        self.width = width
        self.hight = hight
        self.transform = transform
        # labels are stored in a csv file
        self.labels = pd.read_csv(self.root_data)
        self.imgs = [image for image in sorted(
            os.listdir(self.root_img)) if image[-4:] == '.jpg']
        self.len = len(self.imgs)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_name = self.imgs[idx]
        img_path = os.path.join(self.root_img, img_name)
        img = cv2.imread(img_path)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB).astype(np.float32)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (self.width, self.hight), cv2.INTER_AREA)
        img = np.array(img) / 255.0

        if self.transform is not None:
            img = self.transform(img)

        img_id = int(img_name[6:-4])
        label = self.labels.where(self.labels['ID'] == img_id)['Label'].dropna().to_numpy()[0]

        label = torch.tensor(label, dtype=torch.float32)

        return img, label
```

Here is my model:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, h, w):
        super().__init__()
        nw = (((w - 4) // 2) -4) // 2
        nh = (((h - 4) // 2) -4) // 2
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * nh * nw, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 3)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = torch.flatten(x, 1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = (self.fc3(x))
        return x
```

Here's my training code:

```
model = Net(224, 224)

trainloader = DataLoader(ds, batch_size=4, shuffle=True)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

def train_model(epochs):
    for epoch in range(epochs): 
        losses = 0.0 
        for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            img, label = data
            yhat = model(img)
            loss = criterion(yhat, label)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            losses += loss.item()
            # if i % 5 == 99:
            print(f'[{epoch + 1}, {i + 1:5d}] loss: {losses:.3f}')
            losses = 0.0

train_model(5)
```

I have explained the problem but here's the error anyways:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 train_model(5)

Cell In[8], line 13, in train_model(epochs)
     11 print(yhat.size())
     12 print(label.size())
---> 13 loss = criterion(yhat, label)
     14 loss.backward()
     15 optimizer.step()

File c:\Users\Yasamin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py:1194, in Module._call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1190 # If we don't have any hooks, we want to skip the rest of the logic in
   1191 # this function, and just call forward.
   1192 if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1193         or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1194     return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1195 # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1196 full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

File c:\Users\Yasamin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py:720, in BCEWithLogitsLoss.forward(self, input, target)
    719 def forward(self, input: Tensor, target: Tensor) -> Tensor:
--> 720     return F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target,
    721                                               self.weight,
    722                                               pos_weight=self.pos_weight,
    723                                               reduction=self.reduction)

File c:\Users\Yasamin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py:3160, in binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, size_average, reduce, reduction, pos_weight)
   3157     reduction_enum = _Reduction.get_enum(reduction)
   3159 if not (target.size() == input.size()):
-> 3160     raise ValueError("Target size ({}) must be the same as input size ({})".format(target.size(), input.size()))
   3162 return torch.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(input, target, weight, pos_weight, reduction_enum)

ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([4])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([4, 3]))
```

And finally, these are the outputs and the labels that raise this error:

```
yhat=
tensor([[ 0.0097,  0.0184, -0.1236],
        [ 0.0020,  0.0135, -0.1324],
        [ 0.0095,  0.0136, -0.1261],
        [ 0.0027,  0.0176, -0.1285]], grad_fn=<AddmmBackward0>)
torch.Size([4, 3])

label=
tensor([2., 1., 0., 2.])
torch.Size([4])
```

Comment: Your model currently outputs a tensor of shape `(batchsize, #classes=3)`. What is currently your label shape?

Comment: As you can see, batch size is 4 and so model outputs is of size 12. But, label is of size 4. CrossEntropyLoss should output 4 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I found out, `CrossEntropyLoss` works in two ways.

If you pass it `Long` labels, it treats the labels as integer class labels and the shape of `(batchsize)` is correct.

But if you pass `CrossEntropyLoss` labels of type `Float` (as I have in my code) `CrossEntropyLoss` therefore treats your labels as probabilistic (“soft”) labels and expects labels to have shape `(nBatch, #classes)`, that is, to have the same shape
as yhat.

So to fix the error, `label` should be converted to `Long`, before
being passed to `CrossEntropyLoss` (or set it to int64 when creating the tensor)

Also it is worth noting that labels should be from zero to )#classes -1) for `CrossEntropyLoss` to operate correctly.